# Makefile Missing Separator, in section of code that doesn't require a separator

Tags: linux, makefile, vlc

I'm trying to build VLC and I'm receiving this error now:

`Makefile:129: *** missing separator.  Stop.`

I'm not new to bugfixes and having to do some Google-fu to figure out why things don't work. But from what I read, separators are required for recipes. The following section of code that it's complaining about doesn't even contain a recipe:

```
ALL_ALIASES = cvlc rvlc svlc qvlc nvlc
if BUILD_VLC    # The problem line
bin_SCRIPTS = $(ALIASES)
endif
```

I've made sure that all previous recipes have tabs instead of spaces, I made sure that the if statements don't need to be indented in any particular way that I'm missing, and I even read on up the ".PHONY" that's located above it to make sure that's not interferring, which it doesn't seem to be.

I also used `cat -etv Makefile` and to show the beginnings and ends of lines of code preceding the error to make sure there weren't any erroneous tabs hanging out there.

I've looked at way too many posts of this problem and none of them seem to cover this specific use so far.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if` is not a valid statement in GNU Make, which I assume is what you're using.  See the [Conditional Syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditional-Syntax.html) section of the manual.